# how to configure spring security on sping MVC using a login API of another system

Tags: java, spring-security

I want to use Spring security mvc  to login
but I have a problem, I don't know how to switch the spring login configuration from using database to login using an api from another system. Hope everybody help please . Anyone who has tried this configuration will share it with me
Thank you for reading

Comment: I have a similar requirement. Do you have the solution for this already, could you share your idea? @Dynasty Tc Trng